# Как получить глобальный $scope из директивы?

Tags: jquery, javascript, angularjs

Как получить переменные глобального $scope из директивы?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _глобальным_ $scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от типа scope указанного для директивы. Если в директиве не создается свой scope, либо создается дочернbй scope, то есть поле scope, либо не указано, либо установлено в `true`, то так как в ангуляре используется наследование для scope, все поля из скопов выше доступны напрямую.

Если для директивы создается изолированный scope, тогда можно воспользоваться свойствами [`$parent`, `$root`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$root): первое вернет родительский скоп, в котором может быть нужное свойства, второе вернет `rootScope` - скоп самого верхнего уровня, его так же можно проинжектить в директиву, как советуют в соседнем ответе.

Answer (score 1):

В контроллере директивы у вас доступна переменная $rootScope